# How to get complex form field value

Tags: commerce

I have form field name like

```
name="commerce_discount_fields[commerce_discount_offer][und][form][commerce_fixed_amount][und][0][amount]" value="" size="10" maxlength="128" class="form-text required" type="text">
```

How to get value in form alter???

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the following code in validate or submit to get the **% off** form field value.

```
$value = $form_state['values']['commerce_discount_fields']['commerce_discount_offer'][LANGUAGE_NONE]['form']['commerce_percentage'][LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['value'];
```

Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

I guess that like this

```
$form['commerce_discount_fields']['commerce_discount_offer'][LANGUAGE_NONE]['form']['commerce_fixed_amount'][LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['amount']
```